# When i try to save a value with AsyncStorage in React Native, but when i try to retrieve the value, i have {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

The code of my button is:

```
<Button style={styles.shopButtonStyle} onPress={async () => { await this.setState({'selectedShop': negozio['@id'] }); await AsyncStorage.setItem('@shop', "test"); }}>
          <Text>Scegli</Text>
        </Button>
```

And i go to another page with:

```
<Button style={styles.shopButtonStyle} onPress={async () => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Bookingstep2');  
        }}>
          <Text>Continua</Text>
        </Button>
```

In the new page i have:

```
componentDidMount(){
async () => { const shop = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@shop'); console.log(shop);  }
```

}

But the console is empty. Can anyone help me?

Comment: use async  componentDidMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your componentDidMount async instead and use try catch to check the error like:

```
async componentDidMount() {
try {
   const shop = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@shop');
   console.log(shop);
   } catch (error) {
    console.log(error); 
   }
}
```

There may be any error so you can check error in catch block